# Django redirect after login

Tags: python, django

Im creating my first app in Django
I decided I want logging window (smal one with username/password na "Log in" button) on EACH view.
From base.html:

```
<div id="logging">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>Witaj, {{user.username}}!</h1>
    {% else %}
     <form method="post" action="{% url 'harcowanie.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div  style="display: inline-block;">
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; bottom: 25px;">
    <input class="decent_background" type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </div>
</form>
{% endif %}
    </div>
```

Any part of my views.py:

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request=request, user=user)
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'],   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            pass
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        pass
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.

    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'],   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But I'm getting error:

> A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not
>   provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using
>   RequestContext.   warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a
>   template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually
>   caused by not using RequestContext.")

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you use `redirect` in wrong way. Argument context_instance is not supported by this method. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

About error. Ensure that view which rendered page from request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] uses RequestContext or manually import and use the processor to generate the CSRF token([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)).

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the CSRF token is not in your context. A good read to know what CSRF is about: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/).

In order to generate the CSRF token, either enable the middleware in your settings, or generate by hand in your view, then pass it to your template. I strongly suggest to you to enable the middleware :)